# Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor] in spring boot postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm currently trying to paginate and query data from my Problem entity without the nested Account entity in a PostgreSQL hibernate spring boot application. I'm currently getting the error:

```json
Hibernate: select p1_0.id,p1_0.created_at,p1_0.account,p1_0.dislikes,p1_0.likes,p1_0.question,p1_0.title,p1_0.updated_at from problem p1_0
Hibernate: select c1_0.problem_id,c1_1.id,c1_1.name from problem_categories c1_0 join category c1_1 on c1_1.id=c1_0.categories_id where c1_0.problem_id=?
Hibernate: select p1_0.problem_id,p1_0.id,p1_0.code_setup,l1_0.id,l1_0.name from problem_setup p1_0 left join language l1_0 on l1_0.id=p1_0.language_id where p1_0.problem_id=?
Hibernate: select a1_0.id,a1_0.created_at,a1_0.updated_at,a1_0.user_id,a1_0.username from account a1_0 where a1_0.id=?
=> Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]
2023-11-18T22:59:49.562-05:00  WARN 24220 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]]
```

Here is my Problem entity:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "problem")
public class Problem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 765)
    private String question;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Category> categories;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "problem", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ProblemSetup> problemSetups;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account", nullable = false)
    private Account createdBy;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
    private int likes;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
    private int dislikes;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
    
    **getters and setters**
}
```

Account entity:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String userId;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max=100)
    @Column(length = 100, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
   
    ** getters and setters **
}
```

ProblemController:

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("api/v1/problem")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:5173")
public class ProblemController {
    private final ProblemService problemService;

    @GetMapping()
    public PaginationResponse<Problem> getProblems(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute PaginationDTO paginationDTO
            ) {
        return problemService.findAllPaginated(paginationDTO);
    }
}
```

ProblemService:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class ProblemService {
    private final ProblemRepository problemRepository;

    public PaginationResponse<Problem> findAllPaginated(PaginationDTO paginationDTO) {
        Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(paginationDTO.getPage() - 1, paginationDTO.getSize());
        Page<Problem> problems = problemRepository.findAllBeforeTimestamp(paging, paginationDTO.getTimestamp());
        return PaginationMapper.map(problems);
    }
}
```

ProblemRepository:

```java
import com.algowars.core.data.entities.Problem;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public interface ProblemRepository extends JpaRepository<Problem, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Problem p WHERE p.createdAt <= :timestamp ORDER BY p.createdAt DESC")
    Page<Problem> findAllBeforeTimestamp(Pageable page, LocalDateTime timestamp);
}
```

I've tried querying the problems table in different ways and it's still returning the same error. When I call the method on the controller I'm getting this data returned:

```json
[{
  "id":1,
  "title":"FizzBuzz",
  "question":"This is a question test",
  "categories":[],
  "problemSetups":[],
  "createdBy":{
    "id":1, "userId":"1",
    "username":"admin",
    "createdAt":"2023-11-19T03:17:56",
    "updatedAt":"2023-11-19T03:17:56",
    "hibernateLazyInitializer"
  }
}]{
"message":"Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]"
}
```

Is it normal to have hibernateLazyInitializer to be a property without a value on the account?